# Design pattern for allowing all threads of a certain type to access a data queue while minimizing global mutable state?

Tags: c#, multithreading, design-patterns

There's probably a "best" design pattern for this scenario - best in that it minimizes global mutable state and thread-safety problems - but I'm not quite sure what it is, it's most likely magnificently simple, and I'm a clod :).

Let's say I have 10 threads. Each thread reads an external hardware device that picks up RFID signals. Two pieces of hardware can pick up the same signal. When that happens, my threads need to decide which device picked up the stronger signal, which picked up the weaker signal, and do some processing (and in some cases commit to the database). So these threads must share information.

Therefore, I need to create a thread safe queue that all my data reader threads can submit messages to (using lock, blockingqueue, or whatever else), but that **nothing else** can submit messages to. Thread safety is easy enough, but what I don't want is for this thread safe queue to be global/static and accessible to all the rest of the code. Only my reader threads are allowed to access it, not the rest of the program. So I don't want it to be static global or something gross like that.

Should I compose all the threads as part of some kind of shared parent class structure and make the shared queue private to the parent class? That would probably work, but there's surely a better, and more standard design pattern for this problem. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can't you make every thread report to their own separate queue and then implement logic that makes sure no two same signals will be processed in the overall queue?

Comment: You can, and it would be my first choice but there are reasons it won't suit all my needs. I don't just need to eliminate duplicates; I need to do some other logic with the data threads share as well, so I most likely need all the data in one queue.

Comment: But is it vital that you share the data before you enter the global queue?

Comment: Can't you simply pass the queue object to the threads when you start them? Then it doesn't have to be static.

Comment: Vipar, at the moment, the contrators who made this created no global queue. They have Producer1 -> enqueue -> consumer1 dequeues, etc. @Lance, maybe, the threads aren't created in a mannerwhere they share any state with each other, so I'd need to compose them as being in some kind of parent class, maybe?

Comment: This sounds like a great use case for Rx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't need to implement thread-safe queues, you can use the built-in [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Any time you need a class just to hide some data, you can equivalently use a local, closure-scoped variable and a "factory-function":

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

// somewhere in your code...
static Action GetThreadStarter()
{
    var queue = new ConcurrentQueue<Stuff>();
    return () => {
        new Thread(() => MyThreadFunc(queue)).Start();
    };
}

static Action ThreadStarter = GetThreadStarter();

// use it:
void Test() {
    foreach (...) {
        ThreadStarter();
    }
}
```

Of course, if you're only going to create your threads once, and all of them at the same time, you don't need that - **just define the queue as a local variable in the function that creates the threads**.

By the way, it's not clear from your question why multithreading is required (or is a good idea) here in the first place. Perhaps more details could help clarify that.

Comment: One reason for multithreading is that I'm maintaining someone else's multithreaded code, and we're trying to avoid complete rewrites. Another is that we're reading from many hardware devices and there's no need to do all the work on one thread. Done correctly, multithreading is a major performance benefit to the hardware we are reading from.

Comment: I certainly can't define the queue as a local variable in the function that creates the threads, since *currently* the threads are created by repeated calls to a "start this thread" function called by an external DLL (the external dll code is something some contractors are supposed to give us soon, but we don't have). Maybe in the future.

Comment: @JohnSullivan, how do you pass the queue object to the threads right now?

Comment: Currently, they make a new instance of a class with a thread that reads (queues) and a thread that dequeues for every hardware device, with the queues private to one hardware device which is one instance of the class. I want the devices to share a small amount of data. Actually, uhh, can't I just make a queue that's a private static member of that class, and I'm set.. I can't think of any potential drawbacks, actually, are there?  I'm going to see if that works and when it does, I may be embarassed that I asked this question

Comment: Whenever you think you need a `ConcurrentQueue<T>`, reach instead for [BlockingCollection<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx). It's a much more complete and easier to use API wrapper around `ConcurrentQueue<T>`. It supports cancellation, non-busy waits, and even allows you to substitute some other collection than `ConcurrentQueue` if, for example, you want to have concurrent access to a stack or a priority queue.