# Different execution time for part of tasks and ways to solve it

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, task, parallel.foreach

I have tried some parallel approaches with tasks (`Task.Factory.StartNew()` + wait for finish, `Parallel.ForEach`). The problem with this is that I usually split my list into smaller chunks (lists) and then go through their values in parallel. The problem is when I do some things that have higher chances of failing (scraping, expecting some value that may not be there, ...). Some of those tasks finish without almost any problem while others take quite some time and with the methods I am using it always waits till they all finish.

Therefore when I have for example 25 tasks, around 20 of them can finish under 15 minutes while some may take even over 30 minutes. My question would be if there is some way to balance those tasks, like those that are finished could take part of those that are unfinished. Maybe I can have multiple tasks that will run method with just one value and when they finish they will return value and request another one for processing, but I am really not sure if something like that is possible.

Comment: Those sound like some really big lists if it's taking an average of 15 minutes to read through a chunk of the data.

Comment: @RyanWilson: OP mentions scraping so I'm suspecting that a "task" is a batch scrape job. It makes little sense for a single scrape to take this amount of time.

Comment: Yes, one example of usage is going through this batch and scraping some data that may or may not be there in some cases, which is why there is such difference between their total execution time (for example I try one more time and then even if it fails I go to another value in this batch).

Comment: @Restr Have you considered a concurrent queue to hold your data and use a multi-threaded approach, each thread take one job from the queue until all jobs are taken? - [design-pattern-for-allowing-all-threads-of-a-certain-type-to-access-a-data-queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662114/design-pattern-for-allowing-all-threads-of-a-certain-type-to-access-a-data-queue)? I think this would relieve your issue with some batches taking a long time while others are finished.

Comment: *"I usually split my list into smaller chunks (lists) and then go through their values in parallel. [...] I have for example 25 tasks..."* -- What is the workload of each task? Is it one value, or is it a chunk of values (a list)? If its a list, what is the reason that you have chunkified the workload?